# How to access data from multiple tables

Tags: c#, linq

How to write linq query to access data from multiple table.How do you write Linq query for the following sql query:-

```
"select * from user,employee where user.Name='smith' and employee.company='xyz'"
```

Comment: It looks like you are doing a cross-join (old timers like me call it a "cartesian join").  Is that intentional? (where you are are not relating the user and employee tables, so you will get every combination of user and employee where user.name = 'Smith' and employee.company = 'xyz'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do it.

```
var q = from u in db.user
        from e in db.employee
        where u.Name == "smith" && e.company == "xyz"
        select new
        {
           User = u,
           Employee = e
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which linq provider you use. For example, assuming you have the foreign keys defined correctly, entity framework creates what they call "Navigation Properties". So you can easily write a linq query like the above in this fashion:

```
var query = data.Where(employee => employee.Name == "Smith" && employee.Company.Name == "xyz");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from u in context.User
             from e in context.Employee
             where (u.Name == "smith" && e.company == "xyz")
```